# 'undefined' text at the start of the ajax result

Tags: html, xml, ajax

I have an AJAX function to be called on body onLoad. That AJAX calls a XML file.

Here are my codes.

**AJAX:**

```
function loadXml(b,c)
{
var xmlhttp;
var txt,x,xx,i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("POST");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<span class='nphead'>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</span><div class='divider'><div class='divtop'></div><div class='divbot'></div></div>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<span class='nphead'> </span><div class='divider'><div class='divtop'></div><div class='divbot'></div></div>";
          }
        }
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("CONTENT");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<p class='pcontent'>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</p>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<p> </p><div class='divider'><div class='divtop'></div><div class='divbot'></div></div>";
          }
        }
      }
    document.getElementById(c).innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",b,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**BODY:**

```
<body onLoad="loadXml('/content/blog/content.xml','posts')">
<div class="wrap">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="content g_c" id="posts">
    </div>
</div>

//some more stuffs. some stuffs deleted
</body>
```

And the **CONTENT.XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BLOG>
    <POST>
        <TITLE>Title!</TITLE>
        <CONTENT>
        content
        </CONTENT>
</POST>
</BLOG>
```

The results are nice, but the problem is the result would be: (the **bold** words is what I only expected to be shown)

undefined **Title!**

**content**

Why is there the word "undefined" at the start? How would I get rid of it? I can't figure out what causes it. BTW, thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because when the first loop is executed `txt` is undefined, it is better to set the `txt = ''` before the loop starts, so that multiple calls to the `loadXml` will work safely

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("POST");
    var txt = ''; // create txt as a local variable than a global one since it is used only inside the onreadystatechange method
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<span class='nphead'>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</span><div class='divider'><div class='divtop'></div><div class='divbot'></div></div>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<span class='nphead'> </span><div class='divider'><div class='divtop'></div><div class='divbot'></div></div>";
          }
        }
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("CONTENT");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<p class='pcontent'>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</p>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<p> </p><div class='divider'><div class='divtop'></div><div class='divbot'></div></div>";
          }
        }
      }
    document.getElementById(c).innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You never initialized `txt` before you concatenated the result on it, thus `txt === undefined` before any concatenation.

Use `var txt = "", ...` instead.